# Functional tests with vagrant in docker

Tags: python, docker, vagrant

To test some parts of code which require a fresh VM I use Vagrant. To automate testing I use `python-vagrant` package with which I automatically create and destroy VMs.

The problem is that I switched to Docker, so my app in now containerized and therefore I run tests inside a testing container. Even if I install Vagrant inside a container it complains that there is no VirtualBox around. Is there any possibility to solve this problem?

Right now I created a Makefile function which spins up a VM runs a container executing tests and destroys VM at the end. But that does not allow me to perform VM rollbacks between tests and so on.

Comment: did you try with a [vagrant docker provider](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/docker/basics.html) you would place your Dockerfile at the root and use vagrant to operate your docker container

Comment: Sorry but how is this related to my question? I do not need to provision/start docker containers. I need to create VMs on the fly which I can't because I am inside docker.

Comment: would not it be reasonable to migrate the tests infrastructure to docker then?

Comment: @MykolaGurov install VirtuaBox to the docker?